# Providing a json response that references a local variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to restructure a named-JSON response to return a model object (some attributes only), and some associated arrays stored in local variables, however I am unsure what I'm doing incorrectly. The local variables are definitely being assigned with values, however they're not being returned in the response.

This is the structure of what I want returned...

{ name: "Dan", email: "email@email.com", id: "1", open_gifts: [ { objects }, { here }] }

Setup
    @person = Person.find_by_id(params[:id])
    gifts_created_open =  Gift.created_gifts_open(@person)

```
return_object = [@person.name, @person.email, @person.id, gifts_created_open]
```

Now this, returns a JSON object with the details, but its wrapped in an array, and I'm trying to return just a named object, with the associated array inside it.

```
render :json => return_object
```

And this returns a named object, but its missing the array. What gives??

```
render :json => @person.to_json(:gifts_created_open, :only => [:name, :email, :id] )
```

Many thanks with this. I've already spent several hours :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
return_object = {name:@person.name, email:@person.email, id:@person.id, gifts:gifts_created_open}.to_json
```